# Python function returns the same output with different parameters

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Here is a function that iterates through 6 folders named in the 'CATEGORIES' array and after turning them into tensors, returns lists.

However, when I run the same function with different directories as arguments, it gives the same output.

Here is the code:

```
def preprocess(directory, img_size):
    X = []
    Y = []
    CATEGORIES = ['buildings', 'forest', 'glacier', 'mountain', 'sea', 'street']

    label = 0
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            tensor = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
            tensor = cv2.resize(tensor, (img_size, img_size))
            X.append(tensor)
            Y.append(label)
        label +=1
    
    return X, Y

TRAIN_DIRECTORY = 'Data/seg_train'
TEST_DIRECTORY = 'Data/seg_test'

train_X, train_Y = preprocess(TRAIN_DIRECTORY, 150)
test_X, test_Y = preprocess(TEST_DIRECTORY, 150)
```

Here is the output when I compare train and test arrays:

```
print("Train array size: ",len(train_Y), "\nTest array size: ",len(test_Y))
```

```
Output:
Train array size:  14034 
Test array size:  14034
```

Comment: Maybe the two directories have the same number of files in them?

Comment: You're only printing the lengths of the results, not the results themselves. So the values could be very different.

Comment: Python is case-sensitive: the `DIRECTORY` you use in your function isn't the `directory` passed to it as a parameter. So the function in fact ignores the `directory` it is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here, this code should work:

```
def preprocess(directory, img_size):
    X = []
    Y = []
    CATEGORIES = ['buildings', 'forest', 'glacier', 'mountain', 'sea', 'street']

    label = 0
    path = os.path.join(directory, CATEGORIES[label])
    while os.path.exists(path):
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            tensor = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
            tensor = cv2.resize(tensor, (img_size, img_size))
            X.append(tensor)
            Y.append(label)
        label += 1
        path = os.path.join(directory, CATEGORIES[label])
    
    return X, Y

TRAIN_DIRECTORY = 'Data/seg_train'
TEST_DIRECTORY = 'Data/seg_test'

train_X, train_Y = preprocess(TRAIN_DIRECTORY, 150)
test_X, test_Y = preprocess(TEST_DIRECTORY, 150)
```

let me know if it doesn't work or if it isn't what you wanted so I can rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using DIRECTORY which is overwriting the last value hence giving you the same number of files, replace it with the parameter you declared in your function

```
path = os.path.join(directory, category)
```

this should fix your issue with the len being the same number of files.